# How to write a new callback function with transformers-huggingface?

Tags: attributeerror, huggingface-transformers

I want to define a specific callback function each time my gpt-2 fine tuned model finishes an epoch of training. To do this, I specified the callback parameter in the call to the trainer class :

```
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=test_dataset,
    callbacks=[my_callback]
)
```

And I wrote a callback function that tests output generated by current epoch model

```
class my_callback(TrainerCallback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, args: TrainingArguments, state: TrainerState):
        print("The epoch has ended.")
```

It doesnt print anything at the end of the epoch

Comment: It looks like you aren't instantiating the class at all. Try passing my_class() as a callback.